# What was the sparkly thing Fred and George were playing with?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Order of Phoenix* movie there's a scene where Fred and George are outside throwing something shiny and sparkly each to other in front of other students  before Umbridge comes and interrupts. What was that thing?

[image: Fred and George playing the sparkly thing]

Comment: @Gallifreyan, ninja'd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These look like [Filibuster’s Fireworks](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dr_Filibuster%E2%80%99s_Fabulous_Wet-Start,_No-Heat_Fireworks), given that the image looks more like how these fireworks were previously displayed in the films.

It’s hard to tell fireworks apart, though, so it is also possible that they are an early version of [Weasleys’ Wildfire Whiz-Bangs](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Weasleys%27_Wildfire_Whiz-bangs), magical fireworks later deployed to great effect against Umbridge:

On balance, given that Umbridge was able to stop it, it seems more likely to be Filibuster’s, given her total incompetence at stopping Fred and George’s own inventions.

Comment: I got the impression it was one of their own whiz bangs, and it was her stopping it earlier that caused them to just shock-and-awe overwhelm her with them later, as a special kind of revenge. However, that was just my view from a recent first watch of the the movie so it could be totally wrong :)